# How can I resolve this Unsorted Data error in Neo4J-admin import

Tags: java, neo4j

After a bit of trial and error I've managed to coerce my data into a set of CSV files that are initially accepted by Neo4j-admin import. However at around 70% of the import of the largest file the program crashes with an `Unsorted data, a > b Failure` error. I haven't found anything about needing to sort data, and I'm not sure on what columns it should be sorted if that is the case. I cleared my data of any NAN values in case this was the issue but it hasn't resolved it.

Full log below, if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

```
bash-3.2$ bin/neo4j-admin import --id-type INTEGER --nodes:User "import/user_nodes.csv" --nodes:Step "import/step_nodes.csv" --relationships:IS_ROOT_OF "import/root_edges.csv" --relationships:COLLECTED_AT_STEP "import/step_edges.csv" --max-memory=8g
Neo4j version: 3.5.8
Importing the contents of these files into /Users/James/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fc317459-d0c3-43c0-b1eb-d16df6b0d172/installation-3.5.8/data/databases/graph.db:
Nodes:
  :User
  /Users/James/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fc317459-d0c3-43c0-b1eb-d16df6b0d172/installation-3.5.8/import/user_nodes.csv

  :Step
  /Users/James/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fc317459-d0c3-43c0-b1eb-d16df6b0d172/installation-3.5.8/import/step_nodes.csv
Relationships:
  :IS_ROOT_OF
  /Users/James/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fc317459-d0c3-43c0-b1eb-d16df6b0d172/installation-3.5.8/import/root_edges.csv

  :COLLECTED_AT_STEP
  /Users/James/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fc317459-d0c3-43c0-b1eb-d16df6b0d172/installation-3.5.8/import/step_edges.csv

Available resources:
  Total machine memory: 16.00 GB
  Free machine memory: 3.45 GB
  Max heap memory : 4.44 GB
  Processors: 8
  Configured max memory: 10.40 GB
  High-IO: true

Import starting 2019-09-17 13:24:26.679+0100
  Estimated number of nodes: 11.60 M
  Estimated number of node properties: 92.81 M
  Estimated number of relationships: 25.60 M
  Estimated number of relationship properties: 0.00 
  Estimated disk space usage: 2.27 GB
  Estimated required memory usage: 1.14 GB

InteractiveReporterInteractions command list (end with ENTER):
  c: Print more detailed information about current stage
  i: Print more detailed information

(1/4) Node import 2019-09-17 13:24:26.905+0100
  Estimated number of nodes: 11.60 M
  Estimated disk space usage: 1.46 GB
  Estimated required memory usage: 1.14 GB
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   5% ∆3s 933ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  10% ∆2s 816ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  15% ∆2s 412ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  20% ∆3s 31ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  25% ∆2s 227ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  30% ∆2s 624ms
.......... ....-..... .......... .......... ..........  35% ∆754ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  40% ∆1ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  45% ∆0ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  50% ∆1s 406ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  55% ∆1s 5ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  60% ∆2s 822ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  65% ∆3s 215ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... .........Exception in thread "DETECT-6" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[10526719] 2efffffbfcd78001 > 2cc08cb655d4d000 | 4194302:3154733
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers$Worker.run(Workers.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[10526719] 2efffffbfcd78001 > 2cc08cb655d4d000 | 4194302:3154733
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.detect(EncodingIdMapper.java:367)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.run(EncodingIdMapper.java:335)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers$Worker.run(Workers.java:126)
Exception in thread "DETECT-5" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers$Worker.run(Workers.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.detect(EncodingIdMapper.java:367)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.run(EncodingIdMapper.java:335)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers$Worker.run(Workers.java:126)
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.issuePanic(AbstractStep.java:155)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.issuePanic(AbstractStep.java:147)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep.lambda$receive$0(LonelyProcessingStep.java:59)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers.awaitAndThrowOnError(Workers.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers.awaitAndThrowOnErrorStrict(Workers.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.detectAndMarkCollisions(EncodingIdMapper.java:442)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:236)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:56)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep.lambda$receive$0(LonelyProcessingStep.java:53)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.detect(EncodingIdMapper.java:367)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.run(EncodingIdMapper.java:335)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers$Worker.run(Workers.java:126)
.  70% ∆1s 791ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  75% ∆0ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  80% ∆1ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  85% ∆0ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  90% ∆0ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  95% ∆0ms
.......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 100% ∆1ms


IMPORT FAILED in 29s 410ms. 
Data statistics is not available.
Peak memory usage: 1.09 GB
Import error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
Caused by:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers.awaitAndThrowOnError(Workers.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers.awaitAndThrowOnErrorStrict(Workers.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.detectAndMarkCollisions(EncodingIdMapper.java:442)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:236)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:56)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep.lambda$receive$0(LonelyProcessingStep.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.detect(EncodingIdMapper.java:367)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper$DetectWorker.run(EncodingIdMapper.java:335)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.Workers$Worker.run(Workers.java:126)

WARNING Import failed. The store files in /Users/James/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fc317459-d0c3-43c0-b1eb-d16df6b0d172/installation-3.5.8/data/databases/graph.db are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state. Starting a database on these store files will likely fail or observe inconsistent records so start at your own risk or delete the store manually
unexpected error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsorted data, a > b Failure:[8948597] 363e6cefb256e003 > 2c000001e9960000 | 1022779:0
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 1):

After following a hunch that there was an issue with my ID field I copied my original ID field to a new column to save if I ever needed to match records back to the original source, and created a new ID column that was a simple range of integers.

This then solved the issue but a new issue occurred which I think explains the original problem. My newly created original ID field threw an error because the numbers were too long to be integers. I reassigned this column from integer type to Long type and the issue was fixed. So my theory is that the original values being used for ID were too long to be stored as integers.